# Where to obtain MySQL community edition software updates for windows platform?

Tags: mysql

I am new to the mysql adminstration. For the Microsoft SQL Server the updates can be downloaded from the microsoft web site/ windows updates.

But I am unable to find the same thing for mysql. I have a couple of MySQL installations running on version 5.6.22. I am unable to locate where I can download the recent patches & updates.

Can anyone tell me how to get the latest patches for mysql on windows platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't apply patch to your mysql, you need to download newer version and install.  Usually if you stay in same branch an upgrade will go easy.

Official how-to : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/windows-upgrading.html

> 2.3.8 Upgrading MySQL on Windows To upgrade MySQL on Windows, follow these steps:
>
> Review Section 2.10.1, “Upgrading MySQL”, for additional information
>   on upgrading MySQL that is not specific to Windows.
>
> Always back up your current MySQL installation before performing an
>   upgrade. See Section 7.2, “Database Backup Methods”.
>
> Download the latest Windows distribution of MySQL from
>   http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/.
>
> Before upgrading MySQL, stop the server. If the server is installed as
>   a service, stop the service with the following command from the
>   command prompt:
>
> C:> NET STOP MySQL If you are not running the MySQL server as a
>   service, use mysqladmin to stop it. For example, before upgrading from
>   MySQL 5.6 to 5.7, use mysqladmin from MySQL 5.6 as follows:
>
> C:> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqladmin" -u root
>   shutdown Note If the MySQL root user account has a password, invoke
>   mysqladmin with the -p option and enter the password when prompted.
>
> Before upgrading to MySQL 5.7 from a version previous to 4.1.5, or
>   from a version of MySQL installed from a Zip archive to a version of
>   MySQL installed with the MySQL Installation Wizard, you must first
>   manually remove the previous installation and MySQL service (if the
>   server is installed as a service).
>
> To remove the MySQL service, use the following command:
>
> C:> C:\mysql\bin\mysqld --remove If you do not remove the existing
>   service, the MySQL Installation Wizard may fail to properly install
>   the new MySQL service.
>
> If you are using the MySQL Installer, start it as described in Section
>   2.3.3, “Installing MySQL on Microsoft Windows Using MySQL Installer”.
>
> If you are upgrading MySQL from a Zip archive, extract the archive.
>   You may either overwrite your existing MySQL installation (usually
>   located at C:\mysql), or install it into a different directory, such
>   as C:\mysql5. Overwriting the existing installation is recommended.
>   However, for upgrades (as opposed to installing for the first time),
>   you must remove the data directory from your existing MySQL
>   installation to avoid replacing your current data files. To do so,
>   follow these steps:
>
> Unzip the Zip archive in some location other than your current MySQL
>   installation
>
> Remove the data directory
>
> Rezip the Zip archive
>
> Unzip the modified Zip archive on top of your existing installation
>
> Alternatively:
>
> Unzip the Zip archive in some location other than your current MySQL
>   installation
>
> Remove the data directory
>
> Move the data directory from the current MySQL installation to the
>   location of the just-removed data directory
>
> Remove the current MySQL installation
>
> Move the unzipped installation to the location of the just-removed
>   installation
>
> If you were running MySQL as a Windows service and you had to remove
>   the service earlier in this procedure, reinstall the service. (See
>   Section 2.3.5.7, “Starting MySQL as a Windows Service”.)
>
> Restart the server. For example, use NET START MySQL if you run MySQL
>   as a service, or invoke mysqld directly otherwise.
>
> As Administrator, run mysql_upgrade to check your tables, attempt to
>   repair them if necessary, and update your grant tables if they have
>   changed so that you can take advantage of any new capabilities. See
>   Section 4.4.7, “mysql_upgrade — Check and Upgrade MySQL Tables”.
>
> If you encounter errors, see Section 2.3.6, “Troubleshooting a
>   Microsoft Windows MySQL Server Installation”.

Comment: yagmoth555, my question is down voted I am unable to figure out why it was. Is it because of not searching enough information in mysql website?

Comment: @PrakashP I didnt downvoted it, but yes usually it's the reason. The site is sometime hard on newcomer admin, just don't take it personally.

Comment: Actually I have done a research well before coming to stackoverflow. But I am unable to figure that patch info. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the latest version of MySQL by following this link :

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

You can also download previous versions in archives :

http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/